# Convert object column dates in same format - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, python-datetime

I have an object column which contains date. I have extracted these dates from a text column. So all these dates are in different format. Which are mentioned below . But all the date are in mm/dd/yyy or mm/dd/yy or similar formats where month/date/year.
How can I convert this column in mm/dd/yyyy format. Most of the values are in mm/dd/yyyy format only but there are also number of values in other format as mentioned.

```
date_df =pd.DataFrame(data =['01/14/2019',
'1/14/2019',
'1/3/2019',
'1/03/2018',
'01/09/19',
'1/09/17',
'1/9/19',
'1/09/13'])

date_df:
01/14/2019
1/14/2019
1/3/2019
1/03/2018
01/09/19
1/09/17
1/9/19
1/09/13

Expected result :
01/14/2019
01/14/2019
01/03/2019
01/03/2018
01/09/2019
01/09/2017
01/09/2019
01/09/2013
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for custom format in strings (objects), if need datetimes only omit `dt.strftime`:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print (df)
          col
0  01/14/2019
1  01/14/2019
2  01/03/2019
3  01/03/2019
4  01/09/2019
5  01/09/2019
6  01/09/2019
7  01/09/2019
```